# Go through object properties to check if string contains

Tags: php, oop, object, foreach

I want to go through every property my object has and check whether it is contained in a given string. The problem is, I now have 10 properties and wrote 10 if/else-cases. I think I can compromise it by writing a foreach loop

Currently it's like this

```
if (strpos($localWrapper->siteContents, $project->company_name) !== false)
    echo "<br>true<br>";
else
    echo 'false<br>';

if (strpos($localWrapper->siteContents, $project->company_street) !== false)
    echo 'true<br>';
else
    echo 'false<br>';
```

and so on.

There must be a way that I can go through every property of the project object and check whether it is contained in the siteContents-string and then print out a true or false depended on the result.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: As you said, with a `foreach` loop. Did you read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)? Did you try anything? This is programming; *doing* is necessary to achieve anything.

Comment: Yes I tried this just to print it out, but got errors

Code: foreach ($project as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $key . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
        }

Error: Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/localoptimizer/public_html/opanalyse.php on line 19
data: Array

Comment: Well, your object has properties that are arrays and those cannot just be `echo`ed out. Nothing surprising there. You will have to think about how you want to handle them.

Comment: @jon he isnt echoing the values :) Im thinking its a multidimentional array, some of the values are arrays.

Comment: @Martijn: He is echoing the values, look at the first reply to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through it:

```
foreach($project as $key=>$value){
   echo $key.": (".$value.") ".strpos($localWrapper->siteContents, $value) !== false ? 'true' : 'false';
   echo '<br />';
}
```

This is really basic though, if you've read the documentation on foreach, you could figure this out yourself :)

a simple google [`php loop through object`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php%20loop%20trhough%20object&ie=utf-8#q=php%20loop%20through%20object) gives A LOT of results, all doing the same :)

---

If your array has arrays as values, you need to go recursive. This functions checks if the value is a string. if so test it to your searchString. If it is an array, do the same for the new array

```
function SeeIfMyValuesMatch($searchString, $array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        echo $key.' ';
        // Check if the value is an array, if so, go 1 deeper
        if( is_array($value){
            SeeIfMyValuesMatch($searchString, $value); // on deeper
        }
        else{
            echo strpos($searchString, $value) ? 'true' : 'false'; // or echo
        }
        echo '<hr />'; // This is just for looks
    }
}

SeeIfMyValuesMatch($project); // And start
```

Small sidenote: This may result in a weird looking text, I didnt make it pretty, just to show functionallity

Comment: I thought of this, too of course, but I'm getting these erros

Warning: strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/localoptimizer/public_html/opanalyse.php on line 18
true

Notice: Object of class Validator could not be converted to int in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/localoptimizer/public_html/opanalyse.php on line 18
true

Comment: That means the value isnt an string. Is the object multidimentional? is it possible for a value to be an array with values? If so, this will not work because it needs strings/ Please provide a `var_dump()` if your $project in your topic

Comment: `strpos($searchString, $value)` in this snippet is not reliable because `0` offset is falsey.